# C# how to remove duplicate objects from a list

Tags: c#

I want to remove duplicate objects from a list. My code works, but I'm still afraid I'll make a mistake. Especially if the amount of data is larger, this solution doesn't make sense to me. I ask for your comments on my code.

```
            // Print the list with duplicates
            PrintList(listWithDuplicates);

            // This code is not working
            noDuplicates = listWithDuplicates.Distinct().ToList();

            // This code is working but I am not sure if it is good practice
            // especially if I have a large number of data
            noDuplicates = listWithDuplicates
                .GroupBy(x => x.input1)
                .Select(x => x.First())
                .GroupBy(x => x.input2)
                .Select(x => x.First())
                .GroupBy(x => x.output1)
                .Select(x => x.First())
                .GroupBy(x => x.output2)
                .Select(x => x.First())
                .ToList();

            // Print the list without duplicates
            PrintList(noDuplicates);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    class Data
    {
        public string input1 { get; set; }
        public string input2 { get; set; }
        public string output1 { get; set; }
        public string output2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: why don't you just use [distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is a better fit for [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0):

You tried to use `.Distinct()` without further telling it how to compare instances of your `Data`-class.

Therefore you could create a `Comparer` class which you'd then pass to `.Distinct()` as a parameter:

```
public class Data
{
    public string input1 { get; set; }
    public string input2 { get; set; }
    public string output1 { get; set; }
    public string output2 { get; set; }
}

public class DataComparer : EqualityComparer<Data>
{
    public override bool Equals(Data x, Data y)
    {
        if (x.input1 == y.input1 &&
            x.input2 == y.input2 &&
            x.output1 == y.output1 &&
            x.output2 == y.output2)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Data obj)
    {
        return $"{obj.input1}{obj.input2}{obj.output1}{obj.output2}".GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Here is an example:

```
var dataList = new List<Data>()
{
    new Data(){ input1="A", input2="B", output1="B", output2="A"},
    new Data(){ input1="A", input2="B", output1="B", output2="A"},
    new Data(){ input1="C", input2="D", output1="D", output2="C"},
    new Data(){ input1="C", input2="D", output1="D", output2="C"}
};

dataList = dataList.Distinct(new DataComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this solution works for me. Although I thought that there would be an easier way to remove duplicates from a list. Especially when one has to compare many items. I assume one should use an array for the variables then.

Comment: Well, hard to guess what your ultimate goal looks like, but take a look at [HashSets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1). A `HashSet` class provides high-performance set operations and it does not allow duplicate elements.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. I just wanted to make sure that my list didn't contain duplicate objects. I didn't know one needed a comparer and the HashSets are completely new to me. I still have a lot to learn. However, if the object has many properties, e.g. more than hundred, one has a lot of coding work with the override-methods.

Answer (score 0):

A friend showed me how to do the job without a comparer and without override methods.

```
noDuplicates = listWithDuplicates.GroupBy(x => new { x.input1, x.input2, x.output1, x.output2 }).Select(y => y.First()).ToList();
```